# Syntax for object?

Tags: coffeescript

I tried to have an object span multiple lines, like in JavaScript, but Coffeescript rejects it.

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x030303, color: 0xdddddd,
    specular: 0x009900, shininess: 300, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } )
```

I'm forced to put a `\` at the end of the line:

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x030303, color: 0xdddddd, \
    specular: 0x009900, shininess: 300, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } )
```

I could also put all the names on different lines, but in some cases I prefer to pack them together.

Are the `\` line continuation and multi-line approach my only options in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#objects_and_arrays).

Comment: @MattBall, the documentation says I can use the braced syntax and mentions nothing about multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use CoffeeScript, don't just write JavaScript.

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial
    ambient: 0x030303
    color: 0xdddddd
    specular: 0x009900
    shininess: 300
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading
```

[CoffeeScript documentation on object literals](http://coffeescript.org/#literals)

---

Edit to make it clearer :

This really builds an object that is passed as argument. Now let's suppose you have "positional parameters and an object", you might write

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
    x
    y
    color: 0xdddddd
    specular: 0x009900
    shininess: 300
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading
)
```

which would be the equivalent of

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(x, y, {
  color: 0xdddddd,
  specular: 0x009900,
  shininess: 300,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});
```

Comment: This works, but it feels odd. It doesn't look like I'm passing one parameter, rather it looks like I'm passing several. What happens when I have positional parameters and an object?

Comment: This really builds an object that is passed as unique argument. See edit

Comment: How do I pass two objects that are consecutive positional arguments and neither fits on a single line?

Comment: or is the point that if I want to split an object onto multiple lines, I have to add each property on its line, but I can still use braces?

Comment: I've added some examples of 2 object arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript ignores newlines, depending entirely on characters like `{}[](),` to mark objects, blocks and arrays.  Coffeescript allows those (in most cases) but also pays attention to newlines and indentation.  Sometimes the combination of these methods confuses the compiler.  If I am unsure how it will compile something I compare some simple cases.

At coffeescript.org in the Try Coffeescrpt tab try these lines:

```
obj = 
  1:1
  2:2

obj = {
  1:1
  2:2
}

obj = { 1:1, 2:2}

obj = { 1:1,\
  2:2}

obj = { 1:1,
  2:2
}
```

All of these work, producing the same Javascript, except the last.  The last gives a 'missing }' error.

It may help to think of the the `\` as escaping the newline.  So the second to the last becomes the same as the oneliner above it.

Some working examples of 2 object arguments:

```
foo
  1:1
  2:2
,
  3:3
  4:4

foo({1:1, 2:2}
  {3:3, 4:4}
)

foo({1:1, \
  2:2}
  {
    3:3
    4:4}
)

foo x,
  1:1, 2:2
, 
  3:3
  4:4
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use Coffeescript's native syntax for this:

```
c_mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial
  ambient: 0x030303
  color: 0xdddddd,
  specular: 0x009900
  shininess: 300
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
```